# Mostrar y ocultar divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css3, cakephp

Tengo el siguiente problema, ya logre ocultar un div de derecha a izquierda, pero lo que pasa es que el segundo div (el que se va a mostrar) no aparece hasta que el primer se haya ido por completo.

Pero necesito que a medida que el primer div se va por la izquierda, el segundo div llegue por la derecha

Miren los códigos:

Primer div

```
 <div id="divHome" class="row visible">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <h1 id="h1HomeTitle" class="lang" key="h1HomeTitle">Laboratorio estrategico</h1>
        <h4 class="lang" key="h4FHomeFirstText">
            Diseñamos a través de las necesidades de <br> marca la mejor ruta 
            para cumplir con sus <br> objetivos y alcanzar resultados.
        </h4>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <?php
        echo $this->Html->image('Procesos.png', array('alt' => 'Proceso', 'key' => 'imgProcess',
            'class' => 'lang', "width" => "650", "height" => "650"));
        ?>
    </div>

</div>
```

Segundo div

```
  <div id="divNeeds" class="row" hidden="true">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <h1 id="h1NeedsTitle" class="lang" key="h1NeedsTitle">Descubrir necesidades</h1>
            <h4 class="lang" key="h4FNeedsFirstText">
                El comienzo de una estratégia funcional es conoces nuestro <br>
                objetivo y que necesidades queremos resolver, de esta forma <br>
                nuestro equipo a través de un laboratorio enlaza un vínculo con <br>
                la marca y da comienzo al plan estrategico.
            </h4>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <?php
            echo $this->Form->create('Need', array('class' => '', 'id' => 'msform'));
            ?>
            <label class="lang" key="h1NeedForm">Aprovechemos el tiempo y comencemos</label>
            <?php
            echo $this->Form->input('client', array('label' => array('text' => "¿Para que marca vamos a trabahar?",
                    'key' => 'lblClient', 'class' => 'lang'), 'placeholder' => 'Dinos el nombre de tu empresa',
                'class' => 'validador txtClient lang', 'key' => 'txtClient'));
            echo $this->Form->input('need', array('label' => array('text' => "Escríbenos acerca de tu necesidad",
                    'key' => 'lblNeed', 'class' => 'lang'), 'placeholder' => 'Agradecemos nos detalles muy bien la necesidad, '
                . 'es nuestro punto de partida para generar ideas quer fortalezcan la estrategia para resolverla.',
                'rows' => '4', 'class' => 'validador txtNeed lang', 'key' => 'txtNeed', 'style' => 'resize: none;'));
            echo $this->Form->input('objective', array('label' => array('text' => "¿Cuál es el objetivo?",
                    'key' => 'lblObjective', 'class' => 'lang'), 'placeholder' => 'Que se quiere alcanzar con la'
                . 'solución de la necesidad, ¿Adquirir usuario? ¿Mejorar ventas? ¿Posicionar la marca? ... entre otros.'
                . ' Agradecemos nos detalles muy bien el objetivo.', 'rows' => '4',
                'class' => 'validador txtObjective lang', 'key' => 'txtObjective', 'style' => 'resize: none;'));
            ?>
            <?php
            $options = array(
                'class' => 'lang',
                'label' => 'Enviar y continuar',
                'key' => 'btnFormNeed'
            );
            echo $this->Form->end($options);
            ?>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Visible class es para saber cual es el div que se esta mostrando.

```
    $(".visible").animate({
                        width: "toggle",
                        opacity: "toggle"
                    }, 2000);
$("#divNeeds").show();
```

Así oculto el primer div, pero no se como ir mostrando el segundo ya que solo se ve cuando el primero no se ve en absoluto

Les mostrare como se va desapareciendo, espero si se logre apreciar en fotos, si no mis disculpas: 
[image: 1][image: 2][image: 3][image: 4][image: 5]

Como pueden ver en las fotos el div segundo se queda quieto hasta que el otro se va

Comment: ¿Has intentando usar la animación en ambos div al mismo tiempo?

Comment: Me oculta el primero, y el segundo no lo muestra, mi suposición es que esta ocultando el primero y tambien "oculta" el segundo.

Comment: Como utilizas la clase visible? En que momento haces el cambio de clases?

Comment: No, cuando subi el codigo no tenia el cambnio de clases, solo estaba probando que se ocultara el primero y se mostrara el segundo ps si funcionaba ya solo tenia que hacer cambio de clases y listo, con un `$(".visible").removeClass("visible");
                    $("#divNeeds").addClass("visible");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primero que nada para que tus divs hagan la función que deseas debes declarar su estilo como el atributo que les pongo abajo:

```
  <div id="uno" style="position:absolute;background:#74DEFF;height:50px;width:600px; font-size:24px;">Videotutoriales.es</div>
  <div id="dos" hidden="true" style="position:absolute;background:#FF0004;height:50px;width:600px; font-size:24px;left:-600px;">Videotutoriales.es</div>
```

Para que estén a la misma altura por la propiedad `position:absolute`, después el segundo div debe estar una posición mas a la izquierda que el otro para hacer el efecto de que aparezca de un lado y por ultimo debes animar ambos elementos en la función y no simplemente hacer un show() la animaron debe contar con la propiedad `queue: false` que es la que dice que no espere a que termine una animación para recién empezar la otra;

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("button").click(function() {
        $("#uno").animate({
          left: "+=600",
          width: "toggle",
          opacity: "toggle"
        }, {
          duration: 2000,
          queue: false
        });

        $("#dos").animate({
          left: "+=610",
          width: "toggle",
          opacity: "toggle"
        }, {
          duration: 2000,
          queue: false
        });
      });
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>

  <button>Animar</button>

  <div id="uno" style="position:absolute;background:#74DEFF;height:50px;width:600px; font-size:24px;">Div 1</div>
  <div id="dos" hidden="true" style="position:absolute;background:#FF0004;height:50px;width:600px; font-size:24px;left:-600px;">Div 2</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Con tu ejemplo adaptado a mi codigo lo hace pero no se queda visible, desaprece, sabes por que?

Comment: Divs: `<div id="divHome" class="row visible" style='position:absolute;'><div id="divNeeds" class="row " style='position:absolute;left:1500px;'>`

Comment: Js `$("#animo").click(function() {
        $("#divHome").animate({                                                           
  left: "-=1500", width: "toggle", opacity:"toggle" },                                                                       { duration: 2000, queue: false
        });
        $("#divNeeds").animate({
          left: "-=1000",
          width: "toggle",
          opacity: "toggle"
        }, {
          duration: 2000,
          queue: false
        });
      });`

Comment: le falta el hidden al segundo div por eso no te lo muestra.

Comment: Listo, con eso lo hace ahora solo tengo una pregunta, mientras se va corriendo el div parece casi miniaturizado, cuando termina si se ve bn, si quiero que quede del tamaño de la pantalla mientras se va corriendo como hago? 
NO se como agregar fotos a comentarios sino les mostraría

Comment: Que bien que se haya solucionado te pediria entonces que marques mi respuesta como aceptada . Sobre lo otro puedes probar las diferentes animaciones  que tiene [animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)  para ver cual es la que mejor se te ajusta  y sobre el desplazamiento puse un valor en duro pero también puedes hacer referencia a valores  con porcentaje (+=100%)

Comment: Ya te di el chulito, tengo una ultima duda, quiero agregar una clase al visible pero eso debe ser cuando ya todo el efecto termine, como hago? simplemente la pongo al final?

Comment: Esto te servira https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19359763/done-after-animate-callback-function?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa